# How to get a csv file dictionary to return certain values with the .get function correctly

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
import csv

def csv_dict_list(csv_file):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file, "r"))
    dict_list = []
    for line in reader:
        dict_list.append(line)
    return dict_list # [line for line in reader]

def applestock(dict_list):
    retVal = []
    for line in dict_list:
        retVal.append(line.get("AAPL"))    
    return retVal # [line.get("AAPL") for line in dict_list]

stocks = csv_dict_list("newcsv.csv")
apple = applestock(stocks)
print(apple)
```

So, I have this program that takes a csv file and converts it to a dictionary, then appends the lines. The csv file contains stocks from three different companies. Here is an example of the text from the csv file:

Symbol,DateAdj ,Close

AAPL,2/6/2012,58.064457

AAPL,1/12/2018,173.059113

So what I need to do is take all of the values from the dictionary, and print out the highest stock that company had, and the date of that stock as well. My program currently has a line.get function that tries to get all of the lines of AAPL data and return it, but the line.get function is not working and is not returning the apple stock, just returning none.

I just need help with the .get function and getting it to work correctly and getting the stock from it returned efficiently.

I ran the program with just the first function and this is some of the values in returned in the dictionary:

```
[OrderedDict([('SymbolDateAdj Close', '')]), OrderedDict([('SymbolDateAdj Close', 'AAPL2/6/201258.064457')]), OrderedDict([('SymbolDateAdj Close', '')]), OrderedDict([('SymbolDateAdj Close', 'AAPL1/12/2018173.059113')])
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
retVal.append(line.get("AAPL"))
```

adds the result of `line.get("AAPL")` to the list.  `line.get("AAPL")` returns `line` if line contains a *key* "AAPL", otherwise `None`.  In your csv rows, "AAPL" is a *value*, the key is "Symbol", so the code should be

```
for line in dict_list:
    if line.get("Symbol") == "AAPL":
        retval.append(line)
```

This code fetches the value of the "Symbol" key, and adds the line to the list if the value is "AAPL".